# Windows freeze after run hololens emulator

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

I launched the basic application on the hololens emulator (only white cube in front of the camera), it was running normally, I tried move with arows, but then windows freeze. I was waiting a few minutes, however I had to restart PC.

Did you meet with same issue ?

[picture of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V36Zw.jpg)

Comment: Does your hardware meet the minimum requirements for running the emulator?

Comment: Here is more detail about problem https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/3198

Answer (score 0):

In case you have an AMD Ryzen CPU

Apparently the Hololens Emulator does not play well with AMD Ryzen CPUs. One solution is to configure the emulator to use one core in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Microsoft XDE\10.0.17763.0\SKUs\HDE\xdesku.xml` (assuming your UWP SDK is version 10.0.17763.0, otherwise change accordingly). Worked for me when I set ProcessorCount to 1 instead of 4. Sadly this will drastically reduce performance.

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/3198